# Finding the matrix of a linear operator with respect to the standard basis

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $f \in End (\mathbb{R}^{3})$ such that

1. $f$ is diagonalizable and it has only two distinct eigenvalues.
2. $f(U) = V$, where $U = \{(x,y,z): x-2y-z = 0\}$ and $V = span ((1,0,1), (-1,1,1))$
3. 1 is an eigenvalue of $f$ and there is a vector in $U$ associated to that eigenvalue.
4. (1,0,-1) is an eigenvector associated to a simple eigenvalue.

Find the matrix of $f$ with respect to the standard basis in terms of as many parameters as you may need.

My attempt:

We first note that $1-2 \cdot 0 -1 = 0$, so $(1,0,1) \in U$. By (3) we can infer that $f(1, 0, 1) = (1, 0, 1)$. Moreover, $1-2 \cdot 0 -(-1) = 2 \neq 0$, so $(1, 0, -1) \notin U$, therefore $1$ cannot be an eigenvalue associated to $(1,0,-1)$. Let $\lambda_{1} = 1,\ \lambda_{2} = a$, $a \neq 1$, be the eigenvalues of $f$ associated to $(1, 0, 1)$ and $(1, 0 ,-1)$ respectively. Since $a$ is simple, and $f$ diagonalizable, there must be a second eigenvector associated to $1$. Hence, the characteristic polynomial of $f$ is of the form

$$
p_{\lambda}(f) = (1-\lambda)^{2}(a-\lambda) = -\lambda^{3}+(2+a)\lambda^{2}-(1+2a)\lambda+a
$$
This also says that $tr (f) = 2+a$ and $\det (f) = a$.

Now to know what $f$ looks like I need a third basis vector which is given by the fact that $f(U) = V$. For example, I´ve tried with
$$
f(1,1,-1) = (-1, 1, 1)
$$

but when I compute the matrix with respect to the standard basis the characteristic polynomial doesn´t match wich must never happen. So either I´m missing something else or there is something wrong with my reasoning. Can anyone suggest me how to proceed?

Comment: Could you write how you computed your final matrix?

Comment: You were invited to introduce "as many parameters as you may need". You already know that $f(1,0,-1)=a(1,0,-1)$ for some $a\ne1$ and $f(1,0,1)=(1,0,1)$. Don't "try" some random vector $(-1,1,1)$ for the image of $(1,1,-1)$. Instead, I would write $f(1,1,-1)=b(1,0,1)+c(-1,1,1)$ for some $b,c$ with $c\ne0$, and see what happens.

Comment: Sorry for the deletion of my answer I had a typo ...

Answer (score 0):

Your reasoning is correct, you have $U \cap V = \operatorname{span}((1,0,1))$ so $v_1 = (1,0,1)$ is an eigenvector of eigenvalue 1.

Now you know that $v_2$ is an eigenvector for the singular eigenvalue $\lambda$ which is thus different from $1$.

There is a last eigenvector which is not in $V$ (let us call it $v_3$) with eigenvalue $1$. But let us get back to it later.

We can easily see that $e_1 = \frac{v_1 + v_2}{2}$ and $e_3 = \frac{v_1-v_2}{2}$ so $f(e_1) = (\frac{1+\lambda}{2},0,\frac{1-\lambda}{2})$ and $f(e_3) = (\frac{1-\lambda}{2},0,\frac{1+\lambda}{2})$.

Now let us find a second vector in $U$ for example $u=(1,1,-1)$, we have $$f(u) = a v_1 + b(-1,1,1) = a v_1 - b v_2 + be_2$$
but $u = e_2 + v_2$, so $f(u) = f(e_2) + \lambda v_2$ which means
$$f(e_2) = av_1 -(\lambda+b)v_2 + b e_2$$
So in the basis $(v_1,e_2,v_2)$ the matrix of $f$ would be
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 &a & 0\\
0 & b & 0\\
0 & -\lambda - b & \lambda
\end{pmatrix}$$
Which has $(X-1)(X-b)(X-\lambda)$, but the characteristic polynomial of $f$ is $(X-1)^2(X-\lambda)$ so $b = 1$.

But $f$ is diagonalisable hence its minimal polynomial is $(X-1)(X-\lambda)$, so we should have $(A-I_3)(A-\lambda I_3)= 0$. Let us compute this.
$$\begin{align*}
(A-I_3)(A-\lambda I_3)&= \begin{pmatrix}
0 &a & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -\lambda - 1 & \lambda-1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1-\lambda &a & 0\\
0 & 1-\lambda & 0\\
0 & -\lambda - 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\\
&= \begin{pmatrix}
0 &a(1-\lambda) & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}$$
So since $\lambda \neq 1$, we get that $a=0$

This gives us after computation $f(e_2) = (-1-\lambda,1,1+\lambda)$.
So the matrix in the canonical basis is:
$$M=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1+\lambda}{2} &-(1+\lambda) & \frac{1-\lambda}{2}\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
\frac{1-\lambda}{2} & 1+\lambda & \frac{1+\lambda}{2}
\end{pmatrix}$$

It verifies all the assumptions. So your only parameter is $\lambda$ and your eigenspace $E_1$ is
$$E_1 = \left\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid x + 2 \frac{1+\lambda}{1-\lambda} y =z \right\}$$
So your eigenspace decomposition is
$$\mathbb{R}^3 = \ker \begin{pmatrix} 1-\lambda \\ 2(1+\lambda) \\ \lambda-1 \end{pmatrix}^T \oplus \mathbb{R} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$$

So $f$ is the identity on the hyperplane and the dilatation of growth $\lambda$ on the line given by $(1,0,-1)$.

Comment: Thank you, I was getting that same matrix but I was also messing up with the arithmetic computing the determinant. What is the minimal polynomial? We haven't covered that in the course.

Comment: @MrGran The minimal polynomial is the smallest polynomial (with division as order) that nullifies $f$ (hence it divides the characteristic polynomial), therefore $f$ is diagonalisable iff there exists a split polynomial with simple roots that nullifies $f$ iff the minimal polynomial is split with simple roots. Hence the minimal polynomial can be given by $\pi_f = \frac{\chi_f}{\gcd(\chi_f, \chi_f')}$ if your field is perfect or if $\chi_f = (x-\lambda_1)^{m_1} \cdots (x-\lambda_n)^{m_n}$ then $\pi_f = (x-\lambda_1) \cdots (x-\lambda_n)$

Comment: @MrGran Also thank you your exercise (while it is not dealing with the most advanced concept of mathematics) is quite interesting and gives me Ideas for my teaching!

Comment: Thank you, I´ll definitely fill in those blanks after the course because the course I´m taking deviates to bilineal forms, metrics, isometries etc. Also, yes I also think it´s a nice exercise, it makes you relate the main ideas about diagonalization of operators. In the final exam I took last semester (for Linear algebra 1) there was one that asked to find an operator in a vector space of dimension $n \geq 2$ with determinant 1, that leaves a one dimensional subespace fixed,  and not equal to the identity operator.

Comment: Yes you can consider $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ these answer come naturally once you're at ease with these concepts

Comment: I used $f(v_{1}) = -v_{1},\ f(v_{2}) = -v_{2},\ f(v_{j}) = v_{j}$ for all $j \in \{3, \ldots , n\}$. If it had dimension 1 it wouldn´t be possible unless it were the identity map.

Answer (score 0):

Your reasoning is correct except your final choice of a seemingly random vector $(-1,1,1)\in V$ for the image of $$w:=(1,1,-1)$$
(actually, we shall see that this guess is correct, but it needs a proof. And we shall see that the matrix $M$ does have the expected characteristic polynomial, contrarily to your report. Hence your computation of $M$, which you don't describe, must be mistaken).

You were invited to introduce "as many parameters as you may need". Let $u:=(1,0,-1)$ and $v:=(1,0,1)$. You already found that $f(u)=au$ for some $a\ne1$ and $f(v)=v$. A priori, $$f(w)=b(1,0,1)+c(-1,1,1).$$

Since the canonical basis $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ is given by $$e_1=\frac{u+v}2,\quad e_2=w-u,\quad e_3=\frac{v-u}2,$$
the columns of the matrix $M$ of $f$ in this basis will be
$$\frac{a(1,0,-1)+(1,0,1)}2,\quad b(1,0,1)+c(-1,1,1)-a(1,0,-1),\quad\frac{(1,0,1)-a(1,0,-1)}2,$$
i.e.
$$M=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{a+1}2&b-c-a&\frac{1-a}2\\0&c&0\\\frac{1-a}2&b+c+a&\frac{a+1}2\end{pmatrix}.$$
The equations of eigensubspace for the eigenvalue $1$ are then:
$$\frac{a-1}2(x-z)+(b-c-a)y=0,\quad cy=y,\quad\frac{a-1}2(z-x)+(b+c+a)y=0.$$
For this subspace to be of dimension $2$ as specified, the conditions are
$$c=1,\quad b=0
$$
hence
$$M=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{a+1}2&-1-a&\frac{1-a}2\\0&1&0\\\frac{1-a}2&1+a&\frac{a+1}2\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Thank you. I was letting $f(1,1,-1) = (-1, 1,1)$ because $U$ gets mapped to $V$ and since both are 2 dimensional subspaces the natural choice is mapping the basis vectors of $U$ to the basis vectors in $V$. Also, if I already know that the trace is $2+a$, couldn´t I use it to conclude that $c = 1$? Because $2+a = tr f = a+1+c$, so $c = 1$.

Comment: Knowing that $v:=(1,0,1)\in U\cap V$ is mapped to itself, "the" natural choice is indeed to map your second basis vector $(1,1,-1)$ to the second vector of *some* basis of $V$ whose first vector is $v$, but not necessarily the basis you were provided. As for $c$, I also noticed that but since it didn't help to find $b$, it was redundant.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, appreciate it.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers